# Is ${\Sigma_2^\textsf{P}}^\textsf{coNP}\subseteq\textsf{PH}$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

I'd like to know if ${\Sigma_2^\textsf{P}}^\textsf{coNP}\subseteq\textsf{PH}$ or not.
I know ${\Sigma_2^\textsf{P}}^\textsf{NP}=\Sigma_3^\textsf{P}\subseteq\textsf{PH}$, and I wish to know if this holds for ${\Sigma_2^\textsf{P}}^\textsf{coNP}={\textsf{NP}^\textsf{NP}}^\textsf{coNP}$.
In other words, can we switch $\textsf{NP}$ and $\textsf{coNP}$ in the exponent and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any language $L$, and for any oracle $O$, we have that $L^O=L^\overline{O}$. Substitute $NP$ instead of $O$, and $\Sigma^P_2$ instead of $L$ and you get that ${\Sigma^P_2}^{coNP}={\Sigma^P_2}^{NP}$.

The statement is easy to see: Assume we have a TM $M$ for $L^O$, we want to build a TM $M'$ for $L^\overline{O}$.

The machine $M'$ will work just like $M$, except for when it asks for an oracle query $q\in \Sigma^*$ and gets result $r\in\{0,1\}$, we will treat it as if we got the result $1-r$ (the binary negation of $r$). We can do this since oracles are guaranteed to always return an answer, even if the query is not in the language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer with its reason. Now that makes sense to me
: )